# List partitions of a number in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, data-partitioning

I need to represent the partitions of a number in a list. The procedure also takes in arguments that determine the max number of partitions and the max value of the initial partition.

```
(list-partitions 5 2 4)
>((4 1) (3 2))
```

Here the initial total is 5, the max number of partitions is 2 and the max initial partition is 4.

Conceptually, I think I should feed the partitioned numbers into a helper function that will construct the partitions for me. But how would I implement that?

***Solved it***

Comment: I made a program to find the partitions of a number at count them. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution in Racket. First, the `partition` procedure (based on [this](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Recn/Partition/) algorithm) generates the complete list of partitions for the integer `n`. Then the `list-partitions` procedure filters the results as requested:

```
#lang racket

(define (partition n)
  (let loop ((n n)
             (acc '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        (list acc)
        (append-map (lambda (i)
                      (loop (- n i) (cons i acc)))
                    (reverse (build-list n add1))))))

(define (list-partitions n max-number max-init)
  (take (filter (lambda (lst)
                  (<= (apply max lst) max-init))
                (partition n))
        max-number))

(list-partitions 5 2 4)
> '((1 4) (2 3))
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I didn't use your solution because we are using Scheme, it gave me the idea of using an accumulator.

Comment: @Jonk Great!. What Scheme interpreter are you using? because Racket _is_ also a Scheme interpreter

Comment: I use Stk (http://kaolin.essi.fr/STk/). I had no idea there were so many different Scheme interpreters.